# Unable to insert records received as parameter in Json format - Azure Datafactory

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I am receiving new records or records to be updated as parameter in adf pipeline.
Also table name as parameter.

Parameter:

```
[
   {
      "application_id":"1b877c3b-f43f-4841-9826-849ba63b42c2",
      "application_name":"Cable Bolting",
      "IsArchived":false,
      "updated_at":"2019-03-12T04:44:22Z",
      "display":"Cable Bolting",
      "IsActive":true
   },
   {
      "application_id":"1b877c3b-f43f-4841-9826-849ba63b42c2",
      "application_name":"Cable Bolting",
      "IsArchived":false,
      "updated_at":"2019-03-12T04:44:22Z",
      "display":"Cable Bolting",
      "IsActive":true
   }
]
```

TableName: tbl_application

Using the below method able to get the records with schema

```
select * from  OpenJson('@{pipeline().parameters.paramJsonRecordUpdated}') 
  with (@{activity('Lookup1_copy2').output.firstRow.ColumnList})
```

Able to insert the new records. But for update records we need key column, unable to extract key column from json as it changes for different tables.

Pipeline Parameter as below

[image]

inside foreach:

[image]

first look up to get schema using table name

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ' nvarchar(max), ', '') + COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='Track' and TABLE_NAME = N'@{pipeline().parameters.paramTableName}'

Select @Names + ' nvarchar(max)' as ColumnList
```

Copy activity source query

```
select * from  OpenJson('@{pipeline().parameters.paramJsonRecord}')
  with (@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.ColumnList})
```

At the sink side of copy activity unable to extract the keycolumn value.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some more snip of your pipeline setup, settings configured ? Sample input - new records received and the expected output

Comment: What activity are you using ? stored procedure ?

Comment: I have put few more details with images.

Comment: what is the sink dataset or connector

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are not allowed to enter any dynamic expression or this option.

> You need to *specify the column names for unique row identification.
> Either a single key or a series of keys can be used. If not specified,
> the primary key is used.*

A way around I see is, get the **key column** from JSON on to the source as an **Additional Column**. You can get the `KeyColumn` name using another lookup activity and set it to a variable for convenience.

You can use [JSON Path Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#PATH) to extract the key column from JSON

[image]

Then reference that column from drop down at the **Upsert settings**.

### OR

Try use **DataFlow**, where you can provide **[custom expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#:%7E:text=In%20the%20sink%20settings%2C%20you%20can%20optionally%20specify%20the%20key%20columns%20of%20the%20cache%20sink.)** for `KeyColumn`

[image]

Comment: Additional column is not listing under key column. And how to take out the id column value from json. it should work for all tables data. key column value is not allowing to add dynamic content also.

Comment: You can use [JSON Path Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#PATH) to extract the key column from JSON  AND did you try DataFlow instead

Comment: How to take out the first column name from JSON, every time my JSON gets new table records. Something like below is it possible?                                            
   @{activity('Fetch Primary Key').output.firstrow.application_id} Apllication id need to be passed dynamically. I can set it in variable but unable to append after firstrow. Any Suggestion or fix for this